# How to kill a Thread when the Home button is pressed

Tags: java, android, multithreading

First of all, i know that there are a lot of questions related to this, but i haven´t found what i need.

In almost every answer they said that you should have a running loop in the `run()` method (which I have) and when you want to kill your `Thread` you only have to set the `boolean` condition of the `while()` to `false`. I understand that, but in my case every iteration takes a lot of seconds because it´s related to the `GUI Thread`. Basically, this `thread` waits until the user presses a button and then it makes more stuff like reproducing some sounds.

So my problem is that it´s impossible to stop the `thread` setting the `boolean` to `false` because it waits for the user, so when the user presses the home button the `Thread` continues his execution, (waiting for the user´s input) and a few time later (when the user´s time for pressing the button expires) reproduces a sound.

Is there another way to kill the `thread` in the `onStop` method or something like that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without knowing android, I'd say that indeed it should be possible that when you detect the event of the user using the home button, you kill the thread. If you can not kill the thread directly, at least you should be able to ping the class (observer pattern) where the method is waiting for user input, and change a variable saying that the user navigated away. (Keep a boolean or something, that is false when the thread should no longer run). But I am not familiar with android threading to say if this is a feasible, or even sensible way :-)

Comment: Maybe you should check that loop condition not just once, but maybe before/after each of those time-consuming steps?!

Comment: Can you explain why you're using a thread to wait for a button click event, rather than just installing an onClickListener() on the button?

Comment: Ok, my explanation was really bad. I have the onClickListener that i use, but i need this Thread to check if the buttons that the user has clicked are correct and more things. I also need to pause this thread in some situations and i cannot do it in the GUI Thread (it crashes obviously)

Comment: I'm sure your problem can be resolved in a different way. Please explain your situation better and post relevant pieces of your code.

Comment: As far as Activity lifecycle goes, you will always receive the `onPause()` call whenever the Activity is being placed "out of focus" be it from a Back Button press, a Home Button press, or even a `finish()` call. You can stop your Thread there.

Comment: Yeah, I know @Bonatti, but the problem is that, i don´t know how can i kill it

Comment: Inside the Thread, call `interrupt()`. Then, disassociate it from a variable, to allow Garbage Collection.: Example: `Thread dyingThread = YOUR_THREAD; YOUR_THREAD = null; dyingThread.interrupt(); ` This is also complimentary to your "while" `while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){stuffs...}`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
}
```

Then the following event WILL get fired for home button presses:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
       //Thread shutdown
    }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I cannot find WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD and i think it´s impossible to receive the Home button signal because of security.

Comment: Did you try? If you haven't tried, don't say it is impossible. let me know if you test it and it doesn't work